# Jquery datepicker in Bootstrap modal pop up not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, popup

I am using `jquery datepicker` in bootstrap `modal popup`.Once we open the popup and we can select the date and click on 'Save' button. The `popup` is closed and page is reloaded and the data is saved in the database.It is working till here as expected.

But, in the following scenario it is not working as expected.

- I open `popup` and close the `popup` without clicking on `'Save'` button
- When I open popup again and enter date and click on `'Save'` it throws `jquery` undefined error.

Following is my code:

```
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="<%=txtDate.ClientID %>">Date:</label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server"  ReadOnly="true" ID="txtDate"  CssClass="form-control datepicker"></asp:TextBox>
    </div><hr/>
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-warning" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" data-dismiss="modal" />
<button type="button" class="btn pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div>
```

My JS code:

```
<script src="<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Rootfolder"] %>/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.2.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">

       var txt1 = '#<%= txtDate.ClientID%>';
       $today = new Date();
       $yesterday = new Date($today);
       $yesterday.setDate($today.getDate() - 0);

       $(function () {
           $(".datepicker").datepicker({

               dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
               minDate: $yesterday,
               autoclose : true
           });

       });

    </script>
```

Am I missing something? Please let me know if I need to add something as I tried for too long and it is not working as expected.

Comment: What's the number of the undefined error? There should be a number.

Comment: Try using id instead of class. ('#txtDate').datepicker({})

Comment: @Fotis Grigorakis it behaves each time differently.Sometimes it throws error and sometimes it just dont postback the page to save the data.I just tried to give you the error number but it is not posting back the page to save and not throwing any error even in the console.

Comment: @Rahul I just tried with id but it did not postback the page and did not save the data. The popup just closed and nothing happens after that. No error even in the console.

Comment: Why is it downvoted?Any issue in the way question is asked?

Comment: But my friend, if you dont paste the number of the error we can understand you issue. There could be hundreds of errors. You must be more spesific.

Comment: Yes true @Fotis.But, I am not getting any error now and post this scenario, none of my server side events work. Nothing happens on dropdown changes.Hope this information might help you to provide me a direction.Will post the number once I get an error.Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Fotis, following is the error. 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried fixing it by reloading jQuery but it did not work. So instead of only closing modal popup on click of 'Close' button I am closing the modal popup and then reloading the page. For this I changed the button to server side control and on click event I am redirecting to the same page.This resolved the issue.

I am posting this because if anyone struggling with similar issue, this might do the trick.Might not be the perfect solution but, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

While closing bootstrap modal, just set datetimepicker to default using set defaults method.

```
$(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
    $(selector).datetimepicker({}).setDefaults();
});
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: @user8403440 refreshing the document which is not a appropriate way to resolve these cases.